# "Правильное" написание и внедрение js кода в MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, frontend, внедрение

Довольно догое время программирую на MVC 5 (знаю что не самая новая технология). И обычно работал с `angular 2+` + `WebAPI`. Теперь мне нужно юзать `MVC` без `API` т е фронт пишется на `*.cshtml` (`Razor` + `js\jQuery`). Возник вопрос, как правильно внедрять `js` код в `cshtml` и какие подходы для этого используются? Понимаю что однозначного ответа не будет, т к многие юзают как им удобно. Но вопрос имеет место на жизнь. Буду рад любому мнению.

Comment: script bundles (использовать бандлы?)